# Haskell mapProp function

Tags: haskell

I'm new in learning Haskell and have same problems with the definning of functions. I have to write a definition for the function mapProp 
which has the ability to map an f to every proposition in a function ( have to look like this)

```
prop = (True ∧ False)
mapProp f prop = f(f(True) ∧ f(False))
```

In other words, whenever mapProposition finds a constructor with a Propositionfield, for example And a b, it first maps f over a and b, then constructs the
And connective from the results and applies f. Whenever it finds a constructor
with no Proposition field, it applies f.

and this is what i have till now :

```
module PropLog where

import Data.List

data Proposition = Const Bool
                  | Var String
                  | And Proposition Proposition
                  | Or Proposition Proposition
                  | Not Proposition

-- CONTRACT
one :: Proposition

-- DEFINITION
one = Or (Const True)(Const False)

-- CONTRACT
two :: Proposition

-- DEFINITION
two = And(Var "test")(Not(Var "test"))

-- CONTRACT
three :: Proposition

-- DEFINITION
three = Or (And(Not(Var"a"))(Var "b"))(And(Var "a")(Not(Var "b")))


-- CONTRACT
mapProp :: (Proposition -> Proposition) -> Proposition -> Proposition

-- DEFINITION 
mapProp f = map f Proposition
```

Comment: What is your question? It seems a lot like "do my homework for me" at the moment.

Comment: I dont know how to define the mapProp function.. I've tried using map and helper function but just dont work so I'm asking for any tipps ??

Comment: Use pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is not your friend here.

You want to define `mapProp` with *pattern matching*. Pattern matching in its simplest and easiest form means writing a separate formula for each alternative of your data type. The syntax looks like this:

```
mapProp f (Const a) = ... 
mapProp f (Var a)   = ... 
mapProp f (And a b) = ... 
... -- continue for the rest of your alternatives
```